# Displaying array in td tag in Haml

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, haml

I have the following div,

```
 - abc.each do |gg, arr = []|
  - gg.items.each {|def| arr.push(def.values) }

  = modal(attributes: {id: 'some-modal', class: 'modal-wide'}, legacy: true) do
    = header('Item Details', attributes: {id: 'some-modal-header'})

    #graph
      - y_axis = array_values(arr)
      %table{data: {chart: 'line'}, class: 'table-hover'}
        %tbody
          %tr{data: { y_values: y_axis, x_values: [3, 10, 12, 20, 32, 35, 50, 52, 90]}}
            - y_axis.each do |y|
              %td= y

    = actions do
      %span= 'hello'
      %button.btn(data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true')= 'close'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. when I hard code y_axis with the values, it works fine. When I use the above code is skips the loop and goes to "actions". Can someone show some direction.

Comment: Hello. You have achieved the above code; it is already written. Can you give example values for all of your variables, and what final HTML (not Haml) you wish to achieve using Haml?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how do you want but as I understood from your code, you want to make a loop for `td` :

```
%table{data: {chart: 'line'}, class: 'table-hover'}
  %tbody
    %tr{data: { y_values: arr, x_values: another_array}}
      - arr.each do |ar|
        %td
          = ar # this will print value of ar from loop of arr
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for or provide me further information so I can modify my answer accordingly

Comment: @vanga : it will be more helpful if you provide us content of your object for array and another array. as well as simple HTML sytax the way you wish.

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion. I have updated stating what I'm trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Haml allows you to easly use ruby iterators and loops:

```
- arr.each do |element|
   %td= element
```

Just remember to start line with `each` with `-` instead of `=`, and that you don't need to write `end`.